# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Label' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Just learning python and trying to write an RPG game inside a tkinter GUI, already have some logic built-in the console but looking to port to a UI. Read through tutorials and no matter how I write this code I keep getting the same error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Label' and 'int'`

```py
pl_health = 100

def health_UP():
    global pl_health
    pl_health += 1
    pl_health.config(text=pl_health)
    print("adding to counter")


    #### PLAYER STATS BAR ####

    bttn_color = "black"

    # PLAYER STATS TITLES #
    pl_health_ttl = tk.Label(game, text="Health:", fg=bttn_color)

    # PLAYER STATS COUNTERS #
    pl_health = tk.Label(game, text="zero", fg=bttn_color)

    # PLAYER STATS BUTTONS #
    pl_health_UP = tk.Button(game, text=">>", bg="white", fg=bttn_color, command=health_UP())
```

I'm just trying to get it to increment up and be able to do this for the other buttons but I keep getting this error message

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Label' and 'int'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here: `pl_health += 1` - `pl_health` does not seem like an integer value to me (which is why I guess you get the error)

Comment: and a general thing, check out the [How-to minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - your code seems to contain a lot of lines that are unlikely to have something to do with the error.

Comment: I see what you mean, I originally set player_health as a variable in the beginning with a value of 100 so that’s what’s throwing me off because it’s set as an integer. Apologize about all the extra codes just took out all the extras.

Comment: ok, still - if you set `pl_health` to integer 100, you can't do something like `pl_health.config(text=pl_health)`, i.e. treating it like an object. You could maybe give `pl_health` object a property `hp` of type integer and set that to 100?

Comment: `pl_health = 100` gets redefined at `pl_health = tk.Label(...` this leads to the `TypeError` at the next call to `health_UP()` doing `pl_health += 1`.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot when I get in front of my computer again.

Answer (score 0):

When you first call it, it would be fine. However, when you call the function for the second time, the variable "pl_health" had been changed to a Label, so you can't "pl_health =+ 1".
You can just change the label name(instead of "pl_health").

Answer (score 0):

I took another look and realize my naming scheme was screwing me up. I called a global variable called player_health and yet also called a similar variable called pl_health. I was getting the two mixed up since one is meant to be a counter and the other is called when the label is created.